# Extracting something specific from BS4 after running a find_all

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying out some beginning web scraping using BS4. I went to a site called `finviz.com` since I have some stuff there I'd be interested in.

```
print(soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'screener-link-primary'))
```

Here's two lines of the output when I print the above^ . How would I extract `"AGO"` and `"AGM"` from this? I tried pasting the line of text as text but it stripped away all the `html` tags...so i pasted it as an image

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAuxq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.text` property to get the text between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags.

```
sample_html = '''
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="aych-ref">AGM</a>
<a class="screener-link-primary" href="aych-ref">AGO</a>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', class_='screener-link-primary')
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: Ok I will try that. Can I ask you another question, how does the for loop work here? I thought traditionally for loops in python worked with a range i.e: for x in range(y,z). how does that loop work without a range?

Comment: In Python, a loop constructed as `for x in y:` works the same as saying `for each element which I call x in an iterable named y:`. In this case, doing `print(str(type(links)))` returns `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` which is iterable. You can learn more about iterables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).